# trace class and nuclear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Maurin (http://www.mscand.dk/article/viewFile/10641/8662) defines nuclear operators like this: A linear operator $A:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_2$ where $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ are separable Hilbert spaces is called nuclear if there exist sequences $\{\phi_j\}$ and $\{\psi_j\}$ in  $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ respectively such that

$A\phi=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(\phi,\phi_j)_{\mathcal{H}_1}\psi_j$

for all $\phi\in \mathcal{H}_1$ and  $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|\phi_j|_{\mathcal{H}_1}|\psi_j|_{\mathcal{H}_2}<\infty$.
Now for a trace class operator the polar decomposition

$A=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sigma_j(A)(.,\phi_j)\psi_j$

where $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sigma_j(A)<\infty$ shows that $A$ is nuclear.
I tried to show every nuclear operator is of trace class but wasn´t successfull so far. Is this true and if why? Many thanks for any help
in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $A = \sum_j \psi_j \phi_j^*$ be given with $\sum_j \|\psi_j\| \|\phi_j\| < \infty$. Then, $A$ converges in operator norm. In particular $A$ is compact. Thus, $A$ has a singular value decomposition, say $A=\sum_k \sigma_k f_k e_k^*$.

Then, we have
$$ 0 \le \sigma_k = (f_k, Ae_k) = \sum_j (f_k, \psi_j)(\phi_j, e_k) $$
and 
$$ \sum_k \sigma_k = \sum_j \sum_k (f_k, \psi_j)(\phi_j, e_k) = \sum_j \psi_j^* \underbrace{\left(\sum_k f_k e_k^*\right)}_{\|\,.\,\|\le 1} \phi_j \le \sum_j \|\psi_j\| \|\phi_j\| < \infty. $$
That is, $A$ is in the trace class.

Comment: Excellent.Many thanks!!

Comment: @user251257 I came across this post and read your answer. I'd be glad if you could explain one detail to me. Why does the inequality between the sums hold? If I use the Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality we still have $\sum_j \sum_k ||f_k||~ ||\psi_j||~ ||\phi_j||~ ||e_k||$. If $f_k$ and $e_k$ are normalized, we're still left with $\sum_j \sum_k ||\psi_j|| ~||\phi_j||$. 
How do we get rid of the sum over $k$? Or did I miss something obvious?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @pcalc you are right. I need to check this.

Comment: $\sum_k f_k e_k^*$ has operator norm $\le 1$.

Comment: Would you explain this argument in more detail?

Comment: @pcalc I expanded the estimation with more details

Comment: @user251257 Thank you for the expansion! Unfortunately, I still don't get the key point, namely why $\sum_k f_k e_k^* \leq 1$. I guess I must miss something obvious?

Comment: @pcalc the $\{e_k\}$ and $\{f_k\}$ are orthogonal normal basis. So $\|(\sum_k f_k e_k^*) x\| = \|x\|$ holds for every $x$. Thus operatornorm is $1$.

Comment: @user251257 oh ok - if that's true my troubles are caused because I misunderstood the notation. Please correct me, if I'm wrong: assuming that Riesz-Frechet is applicable you mean by $\sum_k f_k e_k^* x = \sum_k (x,e_k) f_k = x$? I.e. $(x,e_k)$ is the Fourier coefficient of $x$ with respect to the orthonormal basis $(f_k)_k$?

Comment: @pcalc the image would not exactly be $x$. Think more like a change of bases. The coefficients in the $e_k$ base are the same as in the $f_k$ base.

Comment: @user251257 Do you mean the following thing by "change of basis"?
 $(x,e_k)$ are the coefficients in the $e_k$ basis and we use these coefficients to "represent" a vector $y:=\sum_k (x,e_k) f_k$ with respect to the $f_k$ basis? So, in other words, was my attempt to understand your notation $(\sum_k f_k e_k^*)x$ right?

Comment: @pcalc yes. You understand everything correctly.